# What, exactly, changed with the Cats update?

Tags: production, cats-2019

I've seen a ton of articles about *Cats* receiving an update shortly after release, and based on recent videos the release actually took place, but I can't find any actual changes more specific than the various CGI improvements explained in the leaked release letter.

Is there any good source of side-by-side comparisons on what actually changed?

Comment: The only change I've heard about is Helen Mirren's hands - the original release still has human hands where her wedding ring is visible - but that might just be because it's the most obvious difference for people to spot.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Which is weird, since a couple backup dancers with full effects also wear wedding rings. Thought that was a stylistic choice, but if you have an official comparison that's at least part of an answer.

Comment: Mirren isn't in Cats. Also, you won't get a side-by-side comparison unless you'll have access to both versions, which you'll likely never get. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_(2019_film)#CGI_glitches_and_modified_release

Comment: @BCdotWEB You're right, I misremembered (I haven't seen Cats, just seen tweets about it). It's Judi Dench, not Helen Mirren. This is the original tweet I saw on it (not an "official" source, as far as I know): https://twitter.com/jenelleriley/status/1208659588414758912

Comment: @BCdotWEB Doesn't seem that unreasonable to me. All it takes is two enterprising cinephiles with cameras and one person to find both recordings. Or even a FVX engineer with a twitter dump.

Comment: It hasn't been released anywhere other than theaters has it?

Comment: @sanpaco -- Yes, but as movies these days are released digitally, it's possible for studios to push out an update/fix *after* a movie is released.  Thus early showings might be different than later showings, even during the initial theatrical release of a film. I believe there were minor changes to some Star Wars films during their initial runs -- CGI tweaks and similar adjustments